# Why automatically screen design layout is changing?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a project which is working fine when I am running it from ecplise.

But after creating a .war file when i am deploying it in tomcat 7.0 server directly design of the screen is changing automatically..

I really don't know what is reason behind this pls let me help from this like why this problem occur.

From Eclipse it is fine.
[image: This is coming fine from ecplise]

From server (You can see the footer part.)
[image: from server .. see the footer part]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "changing automatically"

Comment: you realize that each browser renders a page differently

Comment: I am using same system and same browser. (When I am running from ecplise it is fine but when I am running from tomcat I am getting issue in screen design may be because of css) Hope u got my question.@madalinivascu

Comment: are you using the same size for the screens?

Comment: yes I am using same one.@madalinivascu

Comment: can you post some screens>\?

Comment: ya give me a minute.@madalinivascu

Comment: @madalinivascu You can check it out.. I have added screen.

Comment: this seems like a simple css problem

Comment: But why not in 1st one. If css then it should be same in both(from ecplise and from tomcat.) why only from tomcat server??  @madalinivascu